# Why it doesn't work ( C Lang in Dev C++ )

Tags: c, crash, console, factorial

Please tell me, what is wrong here,it compiles but console crashes when i enter the number. I don't know what to write next, i will just write something to make my post possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    unsigned int i,l,p,w;
    printf("Enter natural number excluding 0: ");
    scanf("%d",l);
    p = 1;
    for(i=1;i<=l;i++)
    {
        p=p*i;
    }
    w=p;
    printf("\nFactorial of entered number %d",w);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second argument to `scanf` should be a pointer to the variable, not the variable itself.

Comment: Get a better compiler. GCC prints: `warning: format '%d' expects type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'unsigned int'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%d",l);` you need to insert the address of `l`, which is `&l`.

You should also use `%u` for unsigned ints, not `%d`.

Comment: @user3587082 You are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful to you later on.